# Python how to fix syntax error during runtime

Tags: python, syntax-error

If I receive a string below with syntax error from a noSQL db that stores it in this exact format, how can I assign it to a variable and "correct" the syntax error during runtime. With assumptions that I cannot change how it is stored on a database.

Since this is a syntax error I can't even use string functions like replace or regex to remove the extra quotations enclosing the phone number.

string = "John Doe "(123) 456-7890""

Desired final result would be for it to not throw a syntax error and compile.
I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you are executing python lines (string) comming from database?

Comment: Like that's the result I get from db. I just arbitrary assigned it to variable string to test. I have to do regex on the string but I can't if it throws syntax error before I get there.

Comment: No it doesn't. Please show the full code that gives the error.

Comment: When you get something from DB, that certainly will not be `variable="some string"`, but it would be more like `variable=getDataFromDB()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string assignment indeed throws a `SyntaxError` if executed as part of your code, but it's not an error for that string to be read from from a database.

In which case it works just as if you had single-quoted the string:

```py
string = 'John Doe "(123) 456-7890"'
```

Comment: The problem is the database returns exactly: John Doe "(123) 456-7890" and I can't really manipulate this using single quotes or str() function

Comment: That's okay. That sequence of characters isn't a syntax error when *contained* in a string—only when stated that way in code. It's one reason Python and other languages give you several different ways to quote—so you can represent the hard cases that include quote marks without triggering a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you escape the internal quotes with '\' or enclose string with single quotes.

```
string_param = 'John Doe "(123) 456-7890"'.replace('"', '')
```

if it's multi-line string, you can use this -

```
string_param = """
'John Doe "(123) 456-7890"'.replace('"', '')
""".replace('"', '')
```